# Difference between "а потом уже" and "а потом"?

Tags: перевод, выбор-слова

For context, the phrase I'm trying translating is: "Конечно, побежать и закрыть кран, а потом **уже** устранять последствия потопа" = "Of course, to run and close the tap, and then to eliminate the consequences of the flood". My question is what role does "уже" serve in this sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adverb уже expresses the final completion of the action.

> Of course, to run and close the tap, and **ONLY THEN/only after that**  to eliminate the consequences of the flood".

Comment: No, it's "и только потом" :)))))

Comment: Ok, just then, finally, if you don't like that....